# What to call a column that references another row in the same table?

Tags: oracle

I have inherited a table that contains a column that is used to "chain" between various related rows within the same table.

For instance:
id, bar, reference_id

- 1, 'foo', 2
- 2, 'foo', 3
- 3, 'foo'

I have no idea what to call this structure in order to search for how I should deal with it.   The idea is that the table maintains a sort of living history within itself.   (my problem is that I may have row 1 or 2, but I need to get to row 3 somehow that is agnostic to the number of 'levels' that I need to traverse)

Comment: Take a look http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things in play here. A table that has a self-referential key is said to have a *reflexive foreign key*, though that doesn't look like it applies here because you'll have missing values.

What you're looking for is a *hierarchical query*, which can be achieved in Oracle by using a `CONNECT BY` clause.

They can be a bit difficult to get your head around at first, but there are plenty of good examples on the internet. A good one to start with is [here](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sql/connect_by.html). For once, the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries003.htm) is quite clear too!

Something like:

```
SELECT id, bar, reference_id, LEVEL
FROM yourtable
CONNECT BY PRIOR reference_id = id;
```

... will get you started on your data.

Comment: It can very well be a foreign key, even if the column is null. It then simply points to nowhere. Any non-null value *must* "point" to an existing primary key, but it is perfectly valid to have a null value in such a column.

Answer (score 5):

A term you'll see used for this type of table is *hierarchical* data/table/queries – the table represents a hierarchy, or parent/child relationship of some form. (Sometimes they're simply referred to as trees.)

Oracle has specific SQL extensions for [hierarchical queries](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries003.htm), namely the `start with`/`connect by` keywords.

If you're only looking for leaf rows (i.e. rows with no next "pointer"), you can use the `CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF` in a where clause. Something like:

```
select
  name
from
  foo
where
  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
connect by
  prior nxt = id
start with
  id = 1;
```